# "Your RVM wrapper scripts are too old..." and mixed Mode install

Tags: rvm, passenger

It appears `passenger` and `rvm`'s `mixed mode installation` doesn't work together, or am I doing things wrong?

`nginx` configuration:

```
server {
    server_name a1;
    root   /home/yuri/a1/public;
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/a1-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/a1-error.log;
    passenger_ruby   /home/yuri/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p385@g1/ruby;
    passenger_enabled   on;
}
```

`config.ru`:

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

`app.rb`:

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

Then each request I get the following in `error.log`:

```
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.1332 3277/7ff40ac6b700 Pool2/Spawner.h:796 ]: [App 3310 stdout] 
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.2150 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] *** Phusion Passenger: no passenger_native_support.so found for the current Ruby interpreter. Downloading precompiled binary from the Phusion server (set PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)...
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.2151 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:152 ]: [App 3310 stderr] 
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.2157 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] Attempting to download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/4.0.24/rubyext-ruby-1.9.3-x86_64-linux.tar.gz into /tmp/passenger-native-support-p8ljrh
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.2157 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:152 ]: [App 3310 stderr] 
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.2190 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] --2013-11-17 01:08:38--  https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/4.0.24/rubyext-ruby-1.9.3-x86_64-linux.tar.gz
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.2207 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] Resolving oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com... 
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.2248 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] 109.107.35.58
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.2258 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] , 
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.2259 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] 109.107.35.58
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.2260 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:152 ]: [App 3310 stderr] 
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.2262 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] Connecting to oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com|109.107.35.58|:443... 
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.2820 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] connected.
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.4669 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5795 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] 200 OK
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5797 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] Length: 
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5799 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] 14562
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5800 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  (14K)
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5801 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  [application/octet-stream]
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5805 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] Saving to: `/tmp/passenger-native-support-p8ljrh/rubyext-ruby-1.9.3-x86_64-linux.tar.gz.tmp'
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5808 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] 
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5808 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]      0K
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5809 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5811 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] .
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5812 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] .
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5813 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] .
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5814 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] .
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5815 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] .
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5816 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] .
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5817 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] .
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5818 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] .
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5819 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] .
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5823 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] .
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5824 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5825 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] .
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5826 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] .
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5827 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] .
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5828 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] .
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5830 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5831 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5832 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5833 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5834 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5835 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5836 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5837 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5839 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5840 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5841 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5842 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5843 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5844 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5846 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5847 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5848 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5849 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5851 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5852 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5853 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5854 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5855 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5856 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5857 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]  
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5891 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]               100%  341M=0s
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5891 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] 
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5891 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] 2013-11-17 01:08:38 (341 MB/s) - `/tmp/passenger-native-support-p8ljrh/rubyext-ruby-1.9.3-x86_64-linux.tar.gz.tmp' saved [14562/14562]
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5891 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] 
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5891 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] # tar xzf rubyext-ruby-1.9.3-x86_64-linux.tar.gz
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5942 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] # rm -f rubyext-ruby-1.9.3-x86_64-linux.tar.gz
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5984 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] Checking whether downloaded binary is usable...
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5984 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] Your RVM wrapper scripts are too old, or some wrapper scripts are missing. Please update/regenerate them first by running:
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5984 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] 
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5984 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]   rvmsudo rvm get stable && rvm reload && rvm repair all
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5985 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] 
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5985 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] If that doesn't seem to work, please run:
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5985 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr] 
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.5985 3277/7ff40d53e700 Pool2/Spawner.h:160 ]: [App 3310 stderr]   rvm wrapper ruby-1.9.3-p385@g1 --no-prefix --all
[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.6164 3277/7ff40ac6b700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:849 ]: Could not spawn process for group /home/yuri/a1#default: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::handleErrorResponse(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)' (SmartSpawner.h:459)
     in 'std::string Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::negotiatePreloaderStartup(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)' (SmartSpawner.h:570)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::startPreloader()' (SmartSpawner.h:210)
     in 'virtual Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::spawn(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (SmartSpawner.h:756)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (Implementation.cpp:782)

[ 2013-11-17 01:08:38.6170 3277/7ff40b4ad700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1996 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session.
Error page:
exit (SystemExit)
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb:100:in `exit'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb:100:in `ruby_command'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb:96:in `ruby_command'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in download_binary_and_load'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:147:in `chdir'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:147:in `block in download_binary_and_load'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb:59:in `mktmpdir'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:146:in `download_binary_and_load'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:44:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:336:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:71:in `init_passenger'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:149:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

**UPD** Running `rvmsudo rvm get stable && rvm reload && rvm repair all` and `rvm wrapper ruby-1.9.3-p385@g1 --no-prefix --all` doesn't help.

Comment: what is in `/home/yuri/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p385@g1/ruby`?

Comment: http://sprunge.us/XHFa

Answer (score 1):

you need to follow instructions in the error message:

> Your RVM wrapper scripts are too old, or some wrapper scripts are missing. Please update/regenerate them first by running:
>
> `rvmsudo rvm get stable && rvm reload && rvm repair all`
>
> If that doesn't seem to work, please run:
>
> `rvm wrapper ruby-1.9.3-p385@g1 --no-prefix --all`

Comment: I do nto see anything wrong with it, report it here http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/list

Comment: Okay, but the second command doesn't seem to work whether I run it under rvm manager user or not. And they [say](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/blob/master/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb#L74) "Correctness of these commands are confirmed by mpapis." In truth, I had a hard time deciding even under which user I am to run the first command. Not to mention the second one. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: It appears passenger looks for wrapper scripts only in `/usr/local/rvm` (to be more precise, it searches there twice). So apparently the problem lies in passenger not looking for wrappers in `~/.rvm`. Probably for a reason. Not using a gemset must work. Also, I seem to have global wrappers both in `/usr/local/rvm` and in `~/.rvm`. Is this by design?

Comment: Well, `passenger` appears to not consider `~/.rvm` as a viable option [because](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/blob/master/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb#L220) it has no `rubies` subdirectory in it.

Comment: `rvm wrapper ruby-n.@ gemname` is handy for regenerating wrappers that  are missing or old. Good tip.